# Regular Expression to parse Query Output

Tags: regex, expression

I have a need to execute a metadata query which will dump a list of tables into a file.  However, I need a way to eliminate all formatting besides the tableId itself.  Can this be done through a regex?   Appreciate all help in advance.

```
+-------------------------------------+-------+
|               tableId               | Type  |
+-------------------------------------+-------+
| t_margins                           | TABLE |
| t_rev_test                          | TABLE |
| t_rev_share                         | TABLE |
```

Comment: What regular expressions have you tried and how did they fail? Do you want to keep just `tableId`? Or do you want to keep the row headings too? Or do you just want to get the first column without anything else?

Answer (score 1):

You have some options, but I would suggest something like this:

```
^\| (\S+)
```

It will match on the line from the start, a pipe, a space and then all `non-spaces`.  The `non-spaces` will be your tableId.  Here is a little example in Python:

```
import re

my_string = '''| t_margins                           | TABLE |
| t_rev_test                          | TABLE |
| t_rev_share                         | TABLE |'''

my_list = my_string.split('\n')

for line in my_list:
    match = re.search("^\| (\S+)", line)
    print (match.group(1))
```

This will give you:

```
t_margins
t_rev_test
t_rev_share
```

Answer (score 0):

The following regexp captures just the column values of the first column:

```
^\| (\w+)
```

https://regex101.com/r/gODhra/3